# Flutter local notification custom ringer not working when release build apk or aab

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

im working with Flutter local notification custom ringer not working when release build apk or aab  here is my code

i go this error when i added keep.xml file , iam trying to get custom sound play in background

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:shrinkReleaseRes'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ShrinkProtoResourcesAction
   > Duplicate attribute '{http://schemas.android.com/tools}keep'.
      at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [5,38]
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@layout/l_used*_c,@layout/l_used_a,@layout/l_used_b*"
    tools:keep="@drawable/*,@raw/notification"
    tools:discard="@layout/unused2" />
```

i am trying all the solution but its not working on build release.
my app notification sound working with i install it on real device via usb.
but when i make a build and install in my phone its not working and iam  trying to play the alarm sound in my app using below code

```
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("onBackground: ${message.notification!.title}/${message.notification!.body}/${message.notification!.titleLocKey}");
   var androidInitialize = new AndroidInitializationSettings('notification_icon');
   var iOSInitialize = new IOSInitializationSettings();
   var initializationsSettings = new InitializationSettings(android: androidInitialize, iOS: iOSInitialize);
   FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
   flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationsSettings);
   NotificationHelper.showNotification(message, flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin, true);
  _playAlarmSound();
  //await playBackgroundSoundInNativeCode();
  //Get.offNamed(RouteHelper.getInitialRoute());
}


Future<void> _playAlarmSound() async {
  AudioCache audioCache = AudioCache();
  await audioCache.play('notification.mp3');
}
```